# Is the piecewise-defined function differentiable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

The function is defined as

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2, &\text{ for }x\leq 1\\ \sqrt{x}, &\text{ for }x>1\end{cases}$$ and

Is this function differentiable at $x=1$?

I thought that since $\lim_{x\to 1}$ of $f'(x)$ exists then it IS differentiable. And I think this limit does exist so it should be differentiable. Book says no. My logic must not be correct here.

Comment: Have you drawn a picture of this function?

Comment: Yes I did sketch it and see that the graphs do intersect at x=1

Comment: Yes, hey intersect there, but form a corner so there is no well defined slope. So the function isn't differentiable there. That's what the answer you've accepted says algebraically. The picture would tell you that's the algebra you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}f'(x)$ is not well defined, until we are convinced that $f'(x)$ exists. If $f'(1)$ does exist, we will have that the left and right hand limits defining the derivative are equal. If we denote $f'_-(x)$ and $f'_+(x)$ as the left and right derivatives respectively, we get that \begin{align*} f'_-(x) &= 2\\
f'_+(x) &=\frac{1}{2} \end{align*}
The left and right derivatives exist, but they are not equal. Thus, $f$ is not differentiable.

Comment: Oh of course I see this now. Thank you for taking the time to put this together in such a clear and concise manner.

Comment: I'm now curious if there is an art to selecting piecewise functions such that left and right have equal derivatives at intersection. My context would be choosing constraints and objectives in context of nonlinear optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $\lim_{x \to 1^-} f'(x) = 2$ and $\lim_{x \to 1^+} f'(x) = \frac{1}{2}$, so $\lim_{x \to 1} f'(x) $ doesn't exist.

But to really prove that $f$ is not differentiable in $1$, try to use the definition.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you graph a piecewise function and at any point it doesn't look "smooth" (there's a "sharp" turn), then it is not differentiable at that point.

More rigorously, the derivatives of the two parts of the function are not the same at $1$, so it is not differentiable. Specifically,
$$\frac{d}{dx}x^2 = 2x = 2 \text{ when $x=1$}$$
and
$$\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt x = \frac1{2\sqrt x} = \frac12 \text{ when $x=1$}$$
and clearly, $2\neq\frac12$. Thus the derivative at 1 doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, I now see this.  Thank you very much!!!